# How can I recognize when user has added account in Yodlee Fast Link?

Tags: yodlee

How can I recognize when user has added account in Yodlee Fast Link (for example an investment account) by going to the link.

What I want:

1. I am creating a link to "Fast Link";
2. User are following by this link;
3. He is adding a their account;
4. **And in this point I wanna know that he has added something (for example by callback url). *How?***
  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. You can have a page hosted that can count the hits and use that page as callback URL in extra params for FastLink.

You can get more information on this at

https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web

The extra parameters that needs to be passed for achieving this is as below
***callback=http://google.co.in*** where here google.co.in is your callback page

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: I have added the `callback` parameter in `extraParams` field. Now user have in top right corner the `X` (cross) icon. Only if he has clicked on it he is following to my site. But I wanna know that he has did something even if he closed the Fast Link page. Can I do it? Maybe term `event` best explains what i want instead `callback`.

Comment: By the way the `callback` parameter has not described in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee have introduced a new event subscription service using [webhooks](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Webhooks). It is part of their YSL (Yodlee Service Language) product.

It can trigger events for following –

- the MFA information is requested by the provider site to log in for
  aggregating data
- the Yodlee system has performed the login on the provider site
  successfully
- the Yodlee system has retrieved the account summary information from
  the provider site successfully
- the final status of account addition or update account APIs

Details -

### https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/cobrand/eventSubscription

Please **NOTE** that Webhook event notifications will work only when you try to add the account using YSL APIs (manually).It doesn't work with FastLink. I have been informed by Yodlee Support. They also informed me that till date they don't have any client using webhook service, which was bit scary to know.